# Multiple site hosting: Virtual hosts not working properly

Tags: virtualhost, centos7, web-hosting, apache2

I have a CentOS 7 server running Apache 2, and am trying to host 2 sites. My two domain names are pointed to the server at IP 70.61.231.8.

```
verizondecom.com
windstreamdecom.com
```

On the server, I have a virtual host set up for each site.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName windstreamdecom.com
  ServerAlias www.windstreamdecom.com
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/windstreamdecom.err
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/windstreamdecom.log combined
  DocumentRoot /var/www/windstreamdecom/public
  SetEnv ENVIRONMENT "production"
  <Directory "/var/www/windstreamdecom/public">
    AllowOverride ALL
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName verizondecom.com
  ServerAlias www.verizondecom.com
  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/verizondecom.err
  CustomLog /var/log/httpd/verizondecom.log combined
  DocumentRoot /var/www/www.verizondecom.com/public
  SetEnv ENVIRONMENT "production"
  <Directory "/var/www/www.verizondecom.com/public">
    AllowOverride ALL
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I type in either domain name, I get the first Vhost (Windstream). The URL in the browser also changes to the server's IP address.

What am I missing here? I need to be able to go to both websites, and the URL should be the hostname, not the IP.

Comment: What does `httpd -S` show? (Particularly for the virtualhosts)

Comment: *:443                  70.61.231.8 (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:56)
*:80                   70.61.231.8 (/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/www.verizondecom.com.conf:4)
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/etc/httpd/htdocs"
Main ErrorLog: "/etc/httpd/logs/error_log"
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/run/httpd/" mechanism=default 
PidFile: "/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="apache" id=48
Group: name="apache" id=48

Comment: worth double checking- did you reboot the apache after adding the second vhost entry?

Comment: Yet. I have tweaked the vhost files and restarted Apache multiple time

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the following in your apache config?

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

The `*:80` part needs to match what you use in the `<VirtualHost *:80>` part.

Also is the default config removed?
`

Comment: Yes. That is the first line of the vhost .conf file. I missed that line when I copy/pasted here.